# how can I create a store procedure to insert 4 values into a table?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm creating a java application with components Swing but I don't how to create a stored procedure to insert 4 values into a table or if is better to use a trigger.
This is my interface:

```
Question: ______textbox_____      correct answer:(bonne reponse )
Reponse A: _____textbox______     *A (Radio button)
Reponse B: _____textbox______     *B (Radio button)   [Add button]
Reponse C: _____textbox______     *C (Radio button)
Reponse D: _____textbox______     *D (Radio button)
(levels)Paliers: _______ComboBox___
```

And those are my tables in mysql

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`questions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE `questions` (
  `idquestion` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `question` VARCHAR(150) NULL ,
  `palier_fk` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idquestion`) ,
  INDEX `palier_fk` (`palier_fk` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `palier_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`palier_fk` )
    REFERENCES `paliers` (`idpalier` )
   )

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `reponses`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE `reponses` (
  `idreponse` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `response` VARCHAR(60) NULL ,
  `bonne` TINYINT(1)  NULL ,
  `question_fk` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idreponse`) ,
  INDEX `question_fk` (`question_fk` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `question_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`question_fk` )
    REFERENCES `questions` (`idquestion` )
   )
```

But the question is how can I create the stored procedure to insert 4 values and the same time to insert into the table question with the idpalier (1,2,3)

I tried with this but it's incorrect

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reponses_INSERT
(

IN idreponse int(11),
IN reponse varchar(60),
IN bonne tinyint(1),
IN question_fk int(11)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO reponses(
    reponse,
    bonne,
    question_fk
)
VALUES
(   
    reponse,
    bonne,
    question_fk

),

(   
    reponse,
    bonne,
    question_fk

),
(   
    reponse,
    bonne,
    question_fk

),
(   
    reponse,
    bonne,
    question_fk

),

;

END 

GO
```

By other hand I'm thinking to create a trigger instead of a stored procedure but I'm not so sure about it that. Because I have to insert the question in the table questions as well as the  4 responses in the table responses.

Any ideas?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: as i understand, your procedure will be called during saving form. Why not just call 4 inserts?

Comment: the stored procedure now is correct! but I don't know if it's possible to create a trigger and after to insert the answers throw  the trigger to insert the questions or the reverse.

Comment: @lezti, triggers a used to operate data that already in database. since you a at point when no question and no answer present in database, trigger is useless. You can add trigger on inserting for example question. And first you insert question. At time trigger executing it knows only about question you inserting and all data already in db, and it don't know anything about answers. And there are no way to give answers to it since triggers does not accept parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reponses_INSERT
(
@reponse varchar(60),
@bonne tinyint(1),
@question_fk int(11)
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO reponses(
    reponse,
    bonne,
    question_fk
)
VALUES
(   
    @reponse,
    @bonne,
    @question_fk

)
END
```

You can now pass in the variables and execute this stored procedure. However, this procedure holds for 1 execution. You would have to call it 4 times passing in the new set of variables each time.

Off the back of this, you can add a trigger on the response table to then insert into the question table.